# How to format a multi line string with triple quotes inside using Python?

Tags: python, string, formatting, escaping, string-formatting

I couldn't find this online but basically I have a string like this:

```
s = "name={0},
address={1},
nickname={2},
age={3},
comments=
"""
{4}
"""
"
```

and I need to format this string as is using variables like so:

```
s.format("alice", "N/A", "alice", 18, "missing person")
```

I can't change the triple quotes there because the program that will use my string expects that, otherwise won't work.

How can I have this string declared/escaped correctly?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could use triple single quotes for the string:

```
s = '''name={0},
address={1},
nickname={2},
age={3},
comments=
"""
{4}
"""
'''

print s.format("alice", "N/A", "alice", 18, "missing person")
```

Output:

```
name=alice,
address=N/A,
nickname=alice,
age=18,
comments=
"""
missing person
"""
```

Comment: Thanks this works great. But for some reason the actual text I am using seem to get tabs for every line. Is this normal? If I add name to a new line that happens for that line i.e. it gets a tab in the beginning. If I put it in the same line as ''' then this doesn't happen for that line, so it's good but the other lines still start with tabs for some reason.

Comment: @JoanVenge `'''` preserves all white space. If you start the text from following line the text will have `\n` at beginning. Similarly if you intend the text white space will be there as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is the string I am using:
http://paste.ofcode.org/5uBdzf32hy5BZ7DdrRpYKE

I don't understand why I am getting tabs really. All I am doing is use format and print the result.

Comment: @JoanVenge  I addressed the problem of indentation showing up inside the literal in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37872349/37872992#37872992).

Comment: @JoanVenge If you're using the text exactly as in the link you provided I don't understand why it's happening. Could you double check your code that it's not intended at all? Also check Kevin's answer, it covers the issue well.

Answer (score 10):

You can escape triple-quotes inside a string the same way you can escape any other quote character, with a `\`:

```
s = """name={0},
address={1},
nickname={2},
age={3},
comments=
\"\"\"
{4}
\"\"\"
"""
```

Strictly speaking, you only have to escape *one* of the `"` characters --- enough to prevent a triple `"""` from appearing --- but I find escaping all three makes my intent more clear.

Later...

```
sf = s.format("alice", "N/A", "alice", 18, "missing person")
print(sf)
print('----')
print(repr(sf))
```

...produces:

```
name=alice,
address=N/A,
nickname=alice,
age=18,
comments=
"""
missing person
"""

----
'name=alice,\naddress=N/A,\nnickname=alice,\nage=18,\ncomments=\n"""\nmissing person\n"""\n'
```

[niemmi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37872417/4116239) works, but only if you don't have a mix of `'''` and `"""` triple-quotes inside the string.  Escaping the quote characters with a backslash *always* works.

## Annoyance #1:  Trailing Newline

I printed the row of dashes to highlight that `s` has preserved the newline between the last three escaped quote characters and the triple quotes that actually ended the string.  To remove it from the literal:

```
s = """[as before...]
\"\"\"
{4}
\"\"\""""
```

## Annoyance #2:  Indentations Preserved Inside Literal

The second and following lines of the `s` literal must be flush against the first (left-hand) column.  Triple-quoted strings neatly lined up inside an indented block:

```
def indents_appear_in_string_literal():
    # This looks good but doesn't work right.
    s = """name={0},
    address={1},
    nickname={2},
    age={3},
    comments=
    \"\"\"
    {4}
    \"\"\"
    """
    sf = s.format("alice", "N/A", "alice", 18, "missing person")
    print(sf)
    print('----')
    print(repr(sf))
    return
```

...will preserve the indentations inside the literal:

```
name=alice,
    address=N/A,
    nickname=alice,
    age=18,
    comments=
    """
    missing person
    """

----
'name=alice,\n    address=N/A,\n    nickname=alice,\n    age=18,\n    comments=\n    """\n    missing person\n    """\n    '
```

Comment: To get around the second annoyance, check out the `dedent` and `indent` functions from the standard `textwrap` module. Look up `dedent` here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html?highlight=dedent#textwrap.dedent

Answer (score 1):

You can use @niemmi's approach, which works perfectly well. You can also add a backward slash at the end of each line to indicate you're going to continue on the next line:

```
s = 'name={0},\
address={1},\
nickname={2},\
age={3},\
comments=\
"""\
{4}\
"""\
'
```

Answer (score 0):

just for the case you did not know, today you can just prefix `f""" ... """`

so:

```py
vs = ["alice", "N/A", "alice", 18, "missing person"]
s = f"""name={vs[0]},
address={vs[1]},
nickname={vs[2]},
age={vs[3]},
comments=
\"\"\"
{vs[4]}
\"\"\"
"""
```